# inheriting from an entity class in code first entity framework affecting database

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4

I have an issue with Entity Framework for SQL compact, 4.3.1 installed with NuGet into the following console application (project properties -> output type = windows application if you wish to replicate):

```cs
namespace TestEntityFrameworkInheritance
{
    class DbExampleRecord
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class ExampleModel : DbExampleRecord
    {
        public TimeSpan NotInDb { get; set; }
    }

    class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<DbExampleRecord> ExampleRecords { get; set; }
    }
    
    static void Main()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(
            new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>());
        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            var dummy = db.ExampleRecords.Add(
                  new DbExampleRecord{ Name="test record"});
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

fails on the `db.ExampleRecords.Add( ...` method with:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: There is no store type corresponding to the EDM type 'Edm.Time(Nullable=True)' of primitive type 'Time'

i.e., EF is trying to put the timespan property of `ExampleModel` into the database, but `ExampleModel` has nothing to do with the context, except that it inherits from one of the entity classes.

Can someone help me understand what is going on here?